# 2D Signal Properties of Fourier Transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I was asked this question below.

I have to match i-v to a-j (matching could be one to many or many to one) and i should prove the matchings.

If conjugation is not made, i can assume that $h(n_1,n_2)$ is real.

How can i start solving this question?

Thanks.
[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQjY.png)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** You have to take the DTFT of each side and match. For example (i)
$$
\begin{align}
\mathsf{DTFT}\left\{-h^*[n_1,n_2]\right\}&=\sum_{n_1=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{n_2=-\infty}^\infty -h^*[n_1,n_2]\;\mathrm{e}^{-i(n_1\omega_1+n_2\omega_2)}\\
&=-\left[\sum_{n_1=\infty}^\infty\sum_{n_2=-\infty}^\infty h[n_1,n_2]\;\mathrm{e}^{i(n_1\omega_1+n_2\omega_2)}\right]^*\\
&=-\left[\sum_{n_1=\infty}^\infty\sum_{n_2=-\infty}^\infty h[n_1,n_2]\;\mathrm{e}^{-i[n_1(-\omega_1)+n_2(-\omega_2)]}\right]^*\\
&=-[H(-\omega_1,-\omega_2)]^*\\
&=-H^*(-\omega_1,-\omega_2)
\end{align}
$$
that is (i)-(f).